# Correct life-cycle management of objects in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have several simple C++ classes that hold data. They are hierarchical, each one contains a list of pointers to children (Since I have lots of them in memory, I didn't want to copy them around).

I only work the highest level (pass it around to functions) and would like the destructor on each level to destroy its children, so all I'll have to do do free all of them is call delete on the top most parent. This causes a problem when some of the classes are created on the stack, but this is really just a symptom of the problem.

As I see it, I need to create and destroy objects on the same level and thus know if I should call delete or not. However, this will force me to hold pointers to all of the children and destroy them after each use in my code, a dirtier solution than calling delete on the top most parent.

So, my options are:

1. Never define them on the stack (BAD)
2. Pass a bool in the constructor indicating whether this object should be deleted or not (BAD)
3. Delete objects manually after each use, depending on the way I created them (BAD)
4. Copy the items "locally" (BAD given there may be many thousands of them)
5. Smart pointers? Some framework? (I'm rather limited in what I can use)

Am I missing anything? Any other ideas?

Thanks,
Vadim.

Comment: Can you upgrade (if it's necessary) and use C++11? This is a poster child for `std::move`.

Comment: I don't think I can upgrade to C++11, we're using gcc 3.2 and this project (or issue) is not important enough to upgrade the compiler.

Comment: Another thing - this is not just a C++ issue, there's an OOP design flaw somewhere in what I did and I can't find a good solution.

Comment: Your description of the problem is too abstract. I don't understand why there would ever be a situation where you don't know whether some object is stack-allocated or heap-allocated.

Comment: I only define the classes, I have no control over how they are instantiated when used. I'll correct myself - I *don't want* to have control over how they are instantiated, or I would have used a factory to solve my problem. I seems like too much for very simple POCOs.

Comment: Putting objects on the stack means that they must be destroyed strictly in the order opposite to their creation.  On the other hand, giving objects "ownership" of their children means that the children must be destroyed just before their parent is destroyed (e.g. as part of the parent's destructor) -- but the parent can be destroyed at any time the programmer chooses to do so.  Both are valid paradigms, but I think they may be mutually exclusive -- the LIFO-ordering logic of the stack is too inflexible to support the more flexible lifecycle-behavior of the object-tree.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, you would define a move constructor and call `std::move` on an object before it goes out of scope so it can pass along ownership of resources that would otherwise get `delete`d.

In C++03, the same functionality can be defined without language formalism, but you have to add a state of the object where it's empty. This is often done by introducing a default constructor and implementing `swap`.

The pointers that get deleted should be default-constructed to null, and after the swap (or the copy constructor, or whatever function) passes the pointers into a new container object that will live beyond the scope, they get set to `NULL` so the `delete` has no effect (and making the object unusable, which is "dirty" but not so bad as you can easily ensure the object isn't used for anything after it's moved-from).

Comment: Is this different (performance vise) that simply making a copy?

Comment: @Vadim No "deep" copy is made. In summary you just copy the pointer, then set the old one to NULL to avoid double-deleting. From there, everything just works.

Comment: I'm probably missing something. If I'll define one of the strings as a local variable, the data (the members of the class) will stay on the stack regardless of what I'll do with the pointers. How do I get around the need to copy it out of the stack?

Comment: @Vadim You didn't say anything about strings or raw data on the stack; you said you had a hierarchy of objects, with the top object on the stack.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a silly mistake. Meant to say if I'll define one of the classes as a local variable. Don't know why I wrote "strings".

Answer (score 0):

Consider holding the children objects in a `std::list`. Instead of using `new`, you write a function that creates a new child using `push_back()` and returns a pointer to it. You won't need to destroy the children directly and you will prevent leaks.